# C# - Get all interfaces from a folder in an assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have some WCF services and I have a list of service contracts (interfaces) in an assembly within a certain folder. I know the namespace and it will look something like this:

```
MyProject.Lib.ServiceContracts
```

I was hoping there was a way to be able to grab all files within that folder so I can iterate over each one and grab the attributes off of each method.

Is the above possible? If so, any advice on how to do the above?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should get you all such **interfaces**:

```
    string directory = "/";
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(directory,"*.dll"))
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
        foreach (Type ti in assembly.GetTypes().Where(x=>x.IsInterface))
        {
            if(ti.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ServiceContractAttribute>().Any())
            {
                // ....

            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Incase the DLL is not a CLR assembly, best to handle load exception silently.

Comment: Perfect! I can shortcut it slightly since I know the assembly name, but the rest of it worked great for me.

Comment: the DirectoryInfo and FileInfo objects are lighter weight and security checks can be bypassed in some cases than the corresponding Directory and File Classes.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.IO.DIRECTORYINFO);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV3.5%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true

Answer (score 1):

@Aliostad answer is already posted, but I will add mine as well as I think it a bit more thorough...

```
// add usings:
          // using System.IO;
          // using System.Reflection;
          public Dictionary<string,string> FindInterfacesInDirectory(string directory)
          {
             //is directory real?
             if(!Directory.Exists(directory))
             {
                //exit if not...
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(directory);
             }

             // set up collection to hold file name and interface name
             Dictionary<string, string> returnValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();

             // drill into each file in the directory and extract the interfaces
             DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
             foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in directoryInfo.GetFiles() )
             {
                foreach (Type type in Assembly.LoadFile(fileInfo.FullName).GetTypes())
                {
                   if (type.IsInterface)
                   {
                      returnValue.Add(fileInfo.Name, type.Name);
                   }
                }
             }

             return returnValue;

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers may not work correctly for Assemblies created with C++/CLI (i.e. an assembly with both managed/unmanaged code).

I suggest replacing this line:

```
foreach (Type ti in assembly.GetTypes().Where(x=>x.IsInterface))
```

with this line:

```
foreach (Type ti in assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(x=>x.IsInterface))
```